# Custom Sorting on category page not working in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: category, collection, magento2.4, sorting

I have Magento 2.4.2.

I have written a custom code to add **A-Z & Z-A** filters on category page.

I have added dependency injection using below code

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
```

In below file, I have overridden **setCollection** function

> Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }

        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            case 'az':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc');
                    break;
                case 'za':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc');
                    break;


                    ......
```

The issue is that this function is called twice, the first time it returns proper result (used X-debug to debug query of collection).
And the second time it is called, it messes up the query of the collection by adding some `entity_id` filter and sorters.

Due to which the collection expected isn't coming.

What could be the reason of above function getting called twice.

Comment: what other code you have done for this one, please share that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that when you run it for the first time you will create some variable into the session or cookie or anywhere else you can call it. The second time you run it, you check that if the original variable exists, it will not run into your custom function anymore.